# Is there some way to turn on a "safety dialogue box" when moving/copying files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I can't tell you how many times I've at some point found out that I have a copy of some file/dir/dir structure, or shortcut, just lying around in some other dir where it has not business being. Or even worse: it has been *moved* there from its original position.

It's extremely easy to accidentally perform such file operations in modern Windows' File Explorer.

How can I make it ask every time before it performs any action related to copying or moving files?

While I can imagine that this also will become a bit annoying, it's probably better than the constant stress from fearing that files have moved around or got copies without my conscious consent.

I often wish in general that Windows could be set to some kind of "paranoid superuser mode" where all kinds of "convenient" things are turned off to improve peace of mind and to resemble the behaviour of early versions of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can [adjust drag and drop sensitivity](https://winaero.com/change-drag-drop-sensitivity-windows-10/) and even [disable it completely](https://winaero.com/disable-drag-drop-windows-10/). I have never done this myself, I've just found out about it by searching.

Sensitivity is the distance (in pixels) you have to drag an element for it to register as a drag and drop action.

The setting is stored in the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
```

Values are named `DragHeight` and `DragWidth`. The default value for both is 4. Increasing them should help.

Setting an enormous value (larger than your desktop size, eg. 10000) should completely disable drag and drop.

The setting is applied on logon, so you have to log out and log back in - or simply restart the PC.